# Continue scrolling jQuery mousedown

Tags: jquery, intervals, mousedown

With a left/right arrow icons, onclick of the respective, the container moves 300 pixels left or 300 pixels right.

Can it be set, whereas if the user continues to hold the button down, the container will continue to move in 300 pixel intervals every X (1 or 2) seconds?

```
$(function () {
    $('a.left').mousedown(function(){
        $('#content').animate({'margin-left':'-=300px'}, 1000);
    });
    $('a.right').mousedown(function(){
        $('#content').animate({'margin-left':'+=300px'}, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a mouseup event, and assume that until that happens, the mouse button is still down?

As long as the mouse button is assumed down, set an interval to do something in the meantime...

edit: easiest way to do that would be to set a variable for mouseisdown and then change that on the mouseup event